# What is the meaning of \uE0001.\uE000 in the decompiled source?

Tags: c#

I'm using this proximity card scanner software to read my card for testing. They provide an SDK but it covers everything except desktop scanners, even though their software is able to read it fine. I noticed their software was coded in .NET and I was able to decompile it using JetBrains dotPeek. I'm very close to what I'm needing. I was able to fix the decompiled code except for these 3 lines. I'm unfamiliar with how to handle the encoding:

```
string[] array = ((IEnumerable<string>) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys).Where<string>((Func<string, bool>) (stg => stg.StartsWith(\uE0001.\uE000(27359)))).ToArray<string>();

string str = ((IEnumerable<string>) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys).Any<string>((Func<string, bool>) (stg => stg == \uE0001.\uE000(28615))) ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[\uE0001.\uE000(28615)] : directoryName;

assyTypeKey = index2.Replace(\uE0001.\uE000(28428), \uE0001.\uE000(28439));
```

I know they're Unicode characters but it's looking very foreign to me with that declaration next to it in parentheses. I'm not sure how to handle this.

Here's one of the functions. I know it's ugly but it's decompiled:

```
    public static void LoadSubServices()
    {
      //SubServicesManager._logger.Info((object) \uE0001.\uE000(28243));
      string[] array = ((IEnumerable<string>) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys).Where<string>((Func<string, bool>) (stg => stg.StartsWith(\uE0001.\uE000(27359)))).ToArray<string>();
label_2:
      int num1 = 1;
      while (true)
      {
        switch (num1)
        {
          case 0:
            //SubServicesManager._logger.Error((object) \uE0001.\uE000(28270));
            num1 = 2;
            continue;
          case 1:
            if (array.Length == 0)
            {
              num1 = 0;
              continue;
            }
            goto label_7;
          case 2:
            goto label_31;
          default:
            goto label_2;
        }
      }
label_7:
      string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName);
      //SubServicesManager._logger.InfoFormat(\uE0001.\uE000(28582), (object) directoryName);
      string str = ((IEnumerable<string>) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys).Any<string>((Func<string, bool>) (stg => stg == \uE0001.\uE000(28615))) ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[\uE0001.\uE000(28615)] : directoryName;
label_9:
      int num2 = 1;
      while (true)
      {
        switch (num2)
        {
          case 0:
            //SubServicesManager._logger.ErrorFormat(\uE0001.\uE000(28621), (object) str);
            num2 = 2;
            continue;
          case 1:
            if (!Directory.Exists(str))
            {
              num2 = 0;
              continue;
            }
            goto label_14;
          case 2:
            goto label_6;
          default:
            goto label_9;
        }
      }
label_6:
      return;
label_14:
label_33:
      for (int index1 = 0; index1 < array.Length; ++index1)
      {
label_17:
        int num3 = 2;
        string appSetting1 = null;
        string appSetting2 = null;
        ILoadableServer loadableServer = null;
        string index2 = null;
        string assyTypeKey = null;
        while (true)
        {
          switch (num3)
          {
            case 0:
              //SubServicesManager._logger.InfoFormat(\uE0001.\uE000(28419), (object) appSetting1);
              num3 = 1;
              continue;
            case 1:
              loadableServer = SubServicesManager.LoadSubServiceAssembly(appSetting1, str, appSetting2);
              num3 = 5;
              continue;
            case 2:
              index2 = array[index1];
              num3 = 3;
              continue;
            case 3:
              assyTypeKey = index2.Replace(\uE0001.\uE000(28428), \uE0001.\uE000(28439));
              num3 = 6;
              continue;
            case 4:
              //SubServicesManager._logger.ErrorFormat(\uE0001.\uE000(28442), (object) appSetting1);
              num3 = 9;
              continue;
            case 5:
              if (loadableServer == null)
              {
                num3 = 4;
                continue;
              }
              goto label_29;
            case 6:
              appSetting2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[index2];
              num3 = 7;
              continue;
            case 7:
              if (((IEnumerable<string>) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys).Any<string>((Func<string, bool>) (stg => stg == assyTypeKey)))
              {
                num3 = 8;
                continue;
              }
              goto label_30;
            case 8:
              appSetting1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[assyTypeKey];
              num3 = 0;
              continue;
            case 9:
              goto label_33;
            default:
              goto label_17;
          }
        }
label_29:
        SubServicesManager._loadableServices.Add(loadableServer);
        //SubServicesManager._logger.InfoFormat(\uE0001.\uE000(28496));
        continue;
label_30:
return;
//SubServicesManager._logger.WarnFormat(\uE0001.\uE000(28525), (object) index2, (object) appSetting2);
      }
      return;
label_31:;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like we're going to need a bit more context than just those three lines of code.  What is index2, for example?  Show us more code.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Thanks, but I'm not sure what else I can provide. I'm looking to see if I can find anything relevant.

Comment: @SeM, there is nothing wrong with `goto`s as long as you know what you are doing. Some of the many famous, commonly used libraries already use `goto`. Do not jump on the hate wagon, if you do not what you are doing

Comment: Don't worry about it guys if you can't figure it out. I wasn't sure if there was some character trickery I wasn't aware of going on. I'll contact their support and delete this if it's a headache.

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü Of course, if there is some keyword in language, probably it has some use to it. But I don't think you can provide me a live example of using `goto` which would be only/best solution.

Comment: I guess there must be somewhere in the code some assignments for all the \uE0001.... variables/constants

Comment: @user3125278 actual problem is, that for example at this line `stg.StartsWith(\uE0001.\uE000(27359))`, `string`'s `StartsWith` accepts a `string` as a first parameter. But `\uE0001.\uE000(27359)` is not a `strgin` as you can see.

Comment: Just opened my eyes: There is a static class named \uE0001 with a static method named \uE000 which takes an int argument

Comment: Yeah definitely. I know I could convert those unicode characters but whatever is in those parentheses is weird. I'll delete this but I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Hmm thanks I'll look around. The decompiler isn't showing it as a class and only a unicode character, but I might be able to find the class/method.

Comment: @SeM, Since I am at the office I will not have time to serch github but in some of the database drivers (ServiceStack or MongoDb) had `goto` usages for the performance gains

Comment: Haha you were right @Sir Rufo:   static \uE0001()
  {
    Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    \uE0001.\uE001 = new \uE0001.\uE000(\uE0001.\uE001);
    string name = \uE0001.\uE001(-(-~(((-370044093 ^ 294924866) - -49435728 ^ -320583989) + 10207685) - -240660238 - 233636811 - 414884003));
    \uE0001.\uE000 = new \uE0001.\uE001().\uE001(\uE000.\uE000(executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name)));
  }

Comment: You can reword that question into something like: What is the meaning of ... in the decompiled source? to form a proper question

Comment: I imagine that this code was run through an obfuscator, hence the weird Unicode symbols.